# Yii2 roles and users

Tags: yii2, yii2-user, yii2-user-roles, yii2-rbac

Can I statically define roles in authManager (in `defaultRoles` array in config) and assign them to users so behavior rules define access to actions?
As i have certain roles, I don't want to use `auth_assignment` and `auth_item` and ...
Assuming I create column in user table for role and every user has one role and roles are define in config file.

In fact I want to build access rules like 'admin' for users who are admin (Where yii says '@' for authenticated user and '?' for guest).

Comment: you tried yourself or not.

Comment: I add admin in `defaultRoles` but i don't know how to say yii to check my user role field.@AmiteshKumar

Comment: read this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-filters.html

Comment: You got answer or not @Mehrdad

Answer (score 0):

First create your roles somewhere like params then behaviors function can manage authentication easily

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class'  => AccessControl::className(),
            'except' => [''],//or only
            'rules'  => [
                [
                    'allow'         => true,
                    'actions'       => ['deletepic', 'regenerate'],
                    'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                        return (myAuth(['root','admin']));
                    }
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

myAuth() will check current user role and return true if they role match requested action.